# How to connect PCU to Stepper driver (NEMA 23)

Tags: stepper-motor

- I have bought a stepper motor, NEMA 23 (Bipolar, 4 wires, 23HS30-2804S-PG15)
- I also have PCU 350W 48V 7.3A 115/230V (S-350-48)
- I also have stepper driver (DM556T, Digital Stepper Driver 1.8~5.6A 20-50VDC)

(I hope it fits together..)

I want to connect it together, but:
DMT556T has connections named: **V+ and GND**
PCU looks like this:
[image: PCU picture]

My confusion is like an output is (I think marked) **V+** and **V-** , ground is where I connect it from the wall and it doesn't look marked like an output.

**So how should I connect these together?**

I was googling like crazy and found two:

- a) Some people connected V+ to V+ and V- to GROUND and driver
- b) Some additionally connected on PCU from "a loop" from GROUND to V- (so ground on PCU has input from wall and at the same time is connected back on PCU on V-)

I saw so many videos and saw these approaches I believe - **but none of them explained why and when it is applicable and what drives this decision?**

Answer (score 1):

The A/C (input) side of your supply is Earth, Neutral, and Line.  The D/C  (output) side is V+ and V-.  For the D/C side you usually use the V- as "ground".  You could also use V+ as your "ground" to get a -48 V supply.

This type of supply is "isolated" meaning there is not normally a connection between V- and Earth.  You *can* connect them together, if you need your DC ground to be common with Earth.

The decision comes down to whether or not you want your DC ground to be tied to Earth potential.

Comment: Thank you,  I am sorry but I still do not know:
"The decision comes down to whether or not you want your DC ground to be tied to Earth potential."

I actually do not know :( As I want to just start using that stepper motor. As person I do not have any wishes when it comes to "tied to the Earth potential"

Comment: In your situation, it does not matter.  Let the D/C side float, it won't matter.

Comment: Just use V- as your DC "ground", and V+ as your +48 V.

Comment: ok, thank you then :)

Comment: So I tried that - and wired as advised - surprisingly no explosion and working at the first attempt.

So thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Study a little better the symbology: what you call 'ground' is actually a PE symbol (protective earth). There are many many types of grounds, the PE (the one with the circle all over it) is for protection (avoiding electric shocks) and draining interferences.

The input side of the supply is N + L (neutral and line)

The output side is V- + V+. The ADJ signal is for trimming the output voltage if needed.

N and L are easy to connect, they go to mains (preferrably fused but that's another issue). PE is easy too: it *must* be connected to the mains earth line (green yellow wire, central plug pin). Otherwise in case of fault the supply chassis can go live (and you *don't want* that).

The output from V- and V+ is completely insulated and floating from the input. So V+ becomes the motor voltage positive and V- is the motor ground.

You *can* tie the V- to PE and under some standards you should or you must. For just running the motor it doesn't really matter. In fact, at least in europe, you need to tie it to PE only if it's used for control power.

So there are reasons for tieing PE and V- (you'll see it done around) but nothing directly connected to the motor drive itself